# vmousemove is triggered even when no move has been performed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, jquery-mobile

On iPad the `vmousemove` event is triggered even when no move has been performed. Why's that?

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open http://jsfiddle.net/dcbV7/
2. Tap A div then B. Only tap them, but fast

Result: you see `vmousemove` event is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vmousemove` simulates the movement of a mouse. It would be as if you clicked A div, moved the mouse to B, then clicked it. There would be no other way to get a mouse from one to the other, after all.

If you try this on a device with a mouse, you'll notice that `vmousemove` is triggered every time the mouse is actually moved. The best heuristic they have for mouse-less environments is that touching two points close together in a short amount of time is similar to doing the same with a mouse.

Comment: I've asked about particular line/function, that mimics `mousemove` between two fast taps

Comment: "The best heuristic they have for mouse-less environments is that touching two points close together in a short amount of time is similar to doing the same with a mouse." --- in this case we should see at least 2 `mousemove` events (over A and over B)

Comment: Not necessarily. It's possible the page loaded with your mouse already over A if you have a mouse. When you tap A for the first time in a mouseless environment, where would your mouse have moved from? Without an actual mouse, there's no way to accurately guess.

Comment: right. But still curious about the exact code. I don't see anything explicit so probably it could be a bug